# Install Kernel Mode Display Only Driver（KMDOD）failed on win10 x64？

Tags: wdk, windows-driver

I have tried to install the KMDOD project in a VMware virtual machine.

- [KMDOD](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/video/KMDOD)（a display-only driver given by Microsoft）

I compiled the project on the host machine win10x64 and then tried to install it through devcon.exe in the VM machine, but the command line showed that the installation failed.

The error is listed as follows:
[enter the image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3tvB.png)

My Environment:

- host machine: X64 windows10 VS2019, WDK for Windows 10, version 2004
- target VM machine: X64 windows10 wdk10,WDK for Windows 10, version 2004

Could anyone please tell me how to solve it?

I can install  the other Microsoft example project， just like [Echo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/general/echo/kmdf/).

After I use devcon.exe to install the SampleDisplay.inf, in addition to the above error, I can see an unknown device under the Display category in the device manager.

Comment: OK， I have installed it successfully.